# C++ 'using' operator to make object of std available

Tags: c++

Please have a look at my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;  // I would like to make cin object available
using std::cout; // I would like to make cout object available in source code
using std::get;  // I would like to make cin.get() available
using std::fail; // I would like to make cin.fail() available

factorial(int number);

int main()
{
    int closer;
    cin >> closer;
    while (!cin.fail())
    {
        factorial(closer); // it's obvious going by the name, It's factorial function
        cin >> closer;
    }
}

factorial(int number)
{
    // the function is correct and it's been examined before....
}
```

I use gcc in linux and have this error :

```
factor.cpp:8:12: error: ‘std::get’ has not been declared
factor.cpp:9:12: error: ‘std::fail’ has not been declared
```

Is there any typo or logical error ?

Comment: what is that error message?

Comment: factor.cpp:8:12: error: ‘std::get’ has not been declared
factor.cpp:9:12: error: ‘std::fail’ has not been declared

Comment: shouldn't this be on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `using` for member functions they can be used without issue:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;  // I would like to make cin object available
using std::cout; // I would like to make cout object available in source code

factorial(int number);
int main()
{
    int closer;
    cin >> closer;
    while (!cin.fail()) // fail is part of the cin type and not part of the std namespace
    {
        factorial(closer); // it's obvious going by the name, It's factorial function
        cin >> closer;
    }
}

factorial(int number)
{
    // the function is correct and it's been examined before....
}
```